# In multinomial logistic regression, why do the decision boundaries tend to be parallel to each other?

Tags: logistic, classification, multinomial-distribution

I understand in multinomial logistic regression, the log odds probabilities are calculated with respect to a reference group. I am wondering why this often results in linear decision boundaries that are parallel to each other. Is there a connection between the reference group and parallelness? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In multinomial logistic regression, 
$$
p(k) = \frac{e^{x\beta_k}}{\sum_i e^{x\beta_i}}
$$
where $i, k$ are possible class labels, $x$ - input data, $\beta_i$ - coefficient vector for the class $i$.

Given class $k$ and base class $j$, log-odds are calculated as
$$
\log\frac{p(k)}{p(j)}=\log\frac{e^{x\beta_k}}{e^{x\beta_j}} = x(\beta_k-\beta_j)
$$

The object is classified as $k$ instead of $j$ if  $p(k)>p(j)$, that is, if $x(\beta_k-\beta_j)>0$. The last inequality is linear in $x$. That's why decision boundary of logistic regression is always linear.

Orientation of the decision boundary between $k$ and $j$ is determined by $\beta_k$ and $\beta_j$. If elements of $\beta_k$ are much larger than of $\beta_j$, this orientation is determined mostly by $\beta_k$. Thus, if there is a class $k$ with especially large $\beta$, all the decision boundaries would be dominated by it, and would be nearly parallel.